# How to fix missing output in loops

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I want to be able to run the program again as long as the user desires. But the problem is, whenever I loop the program, it doesn't show the outputs anymore. How do I fix this problem?

```
long numCoco = 0, numPeople = 0;
char again = 'Y';
    do
    {
        cout << "enter the number of coconuts gathered: ";
        cin >> numCoco;
        //validate user input
        while (numCoco < 1 || numCoco > 5000)
        {
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "You have entered the wrong input\n";
                cin >> numCoco;
            }
            if (!cin.fail())
                break;
        }

        for (numPeople = numCoco - 1; numPeople > 1 && !found; numPeople--)
        {
            found = splitCoco(numCoco, numPeople);
            if (found)
            {
                cout << numCoco << " Coconuts, " << numPeople << " Persons, " << " and 1 monkey\n\n";
            }

        }
            if (!found)
            {
                cout << numCoco << " no solution\n\n";
            }

        cout << "Run again? (Y/N): ";
        cin >> again;
    } while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');
```

#### Desired Output

```
Enter the number of coconuts gathered: 25
25 coconuts, 3 persons, and 1 monkey
Run again(Y/N): y

Enter the number of coconuts gathered: 30
30 coconuts, No solution
Run again(Y/N): N
```

#### Actual Output

```
Enter the number of coconuts gathered: 25
25 coconuts, 3 persons, and 1 monkey
Run again(Y/N): y

Enter the number of coconuts gathered: 30
Run again(Y/N): N
```

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: You don't reset `found` to zero on each iteration of the `do { … } while (…);` loop.

Comment: You can also see that your `for` loop is dependent on the value of `found`, which applies to what @JonathanLeffler said

Comment: You can simplify your input loop to this as well: `while(!cin){ cin>>numCoco; }` and then add whatever else you need in that block.

Answer (score 1):

You must set "found" variable to 0 before the for loop.You expect "found" variable to be 0 when the input is 30 but actually the line:

```
found = splitCoco(numCoco, numPeople);
```

never executes in the second iteration.

The problem here is that after the first iteration(when input is 25), found is set to true and in the second iteration(when input is 30), found is still true so both the condition of "for loop" and the condition of the "if block" are false so none of them executes; so nothing is printed and the loop starts over.